# How do I make button that does A the first time but does B the second time I push it?

Tags: swift3, xcode8

I want to make a quiz app that adds points if I get the correct answer and only adds points the first time I click it, but adds no points the second or the third time etc., when I click the button.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var points = 0

    @IBAction func action(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        var firstTimePressed : Bool = false

        if(firstTimePressed == false) {
            firstTimePressed = true
        }
        else {
            points += 0
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you.Also I want to just add points when the first button I clicked is the correct button not add points if I clicked on mistaken button first. @the4kman

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the4kman s answer you can also let the `firstTimePressed` variable in the function but then you have to make it **static**.

```
@IBAction func action(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    static var firstTimePressed : Bool

    if(firstTimePressed) {
        // it isn't the first press
    }
    else {
        // it is the first press
        firstTimePressed = true
    }
}
```

when the function is called at the first time `firstTimePressed` will be set to `false` and so won't pass the if statement and triggers the else which sets then `firstTimePressed` to `true`

Answer (score 0):

Make `firstTimePressed` a **class variable** (i. e. move it out of the function). That way, it will not destroy itself after the function's execution has ended.

```
var firstTimePressed = true

@IBAction func action(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    [...]

    if firstTimePressed {
        points += 1

        firstTimePressed = false
    }

    [...]
}
```

Comment: Thank you.Also I want to just add points when the first button I clicked is the correct button.